# Getting the middle of a way over Overpass API

Tags: openstreetmap, api, overpass-api

I´m trying to import several Ways and Nodes from the OSM. But i dont want to get the Ways as a way with different nodes, only the middle of the way.

In my case, all ways are an area (Parks, Parking etc.) and i only need one point - the middle of the area. I could calculate this after the request, but maybe theres a more elegant way?

Comment: use rel(pivot);out center;>;out; example for a post code centroid http://tinyurl.com/k3nuzcs

Comment: Thank you really much for your answer! I dont get it to work.. I have the following Query: http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/6Jr which includes Ways and Nodes. When i insert your option, i get no result :( Any idea? Thank you!

Comment: Cross post: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27694834/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-middle-of-a-way-from-overpass-api

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the option `center` after the `out` param :

```
overpass-api.de/api/interpreter?data=[out:json];(way(45.305,4.183,45.525,4.582)[leisure=playground]);out center;
```

You now should have a centre for each way element :

```
"center": {
    "lat": 45.4221048,
    "lon": 4.4259259
}
```