# select ways as nodes with way center as node coords

Tags: overpass-api, overpass-turbo

When querying OSM through OverpassTurbo, I notice some locations are ploted as polygons (closed ways) instead of nodes:

[image]

When I clicked on the node I gt this result:

[image]

This is data:

```
{
  "type": "way",
  "id": 140180197,
  "nodes": [
    1535810420,
    9649588958,
    1535810287,
    9649588955,
    1535810413,
    9649588954,
    1535810346,
    1535810420
  ],
  "tags": {
    "addr:city": "Երևան",
    "addr:housenumber": "17",
    "addr:postcode": "0006",
    "addr:street": "Գարեգին Նժդեհի փողոց",
    "building": "retail",
    "building:levels": "2",
    "name": "«Հայրենիք» առևտրի կենտրոն",
    "name:en": "Hayreniq Mall",
    "name:ru": "ТЦ \"Айреник\"",
    "phone": "+374 10 44 64 03",
    "shop": "mall"
  }
}
```

I have this query:

```
[out:json][timeout:25];
area["ISO3166-1:alpha2"="AM"][boundary=administrative][admin_level~"2|5|6|8"]->.a;
rel[place~"town|city"]['name:en'~"Yerevan"](area.a)->.r;
.r out geom;
.r map_to_area ->.m;
  nwr(area.m)["shop"~"mall"];
(._;>;);
out qt;
```

I want to show all data as a node, how can I convert these ways as a node on the map?

https://overpass-turbo.eu/s/1sW7

Comment: Does the "out center" option work for you https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/127754/getting-the-middle-of-a-way-over-overpass-api?

Comment: I used but is it possible to change types to node ? In my app I made a query to persist all nodes , now many malls declare as a way, so Is it possible to change to node ? or I have to change my query in the application to accept,  ways that "role"!= "outer",? @user30184